# Ubuntu 16.04 mic not working

Tags: sound, microphone

I have the following internal MIC that is not working

```
➜  ~ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=312f810c3df3cc2177e6a4930d60d05c18c22a36

Comment: try use pavucontrol to turn it on and off.. check the output devices tab to see if it works...

Comment: Tried that as well. It picks up the mic but does not show that it detects anything

Comment: can we see a screenshot of the input devices tab in pavucontrol?